# ElasticSearch: Aggregation over nested array

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I have some documents that look like this

```
     {
      "reg": "a",
      "timestamp": "2012-10-01T00:06:35+0000",
      "data": [
        {
          "d": 33.2,
          "name": "TEMP",
        },
        {
          "d": 129,
          "name": "PRESS",
        }
      ]
    }
```

Data is a nested array with 2 properties inside (`name` and `d` which is a double)

I want to aggregate the value (`d`) of `TEMP` to have buckets with mean values, for instance.

How can I do that? if I create a simple aggregation on data.d, the aggregation mixes `PRESS` and `TEMP`, that I do not want

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/nested.html) and the [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html)